# Unexpected AttributeError happens even though it should not

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have been working on a script to get some data from the URL using Python and modules `BeautifulSoup`, and `requests`. I divided the code into few functions to add some code modularity and even though I expect the code to work well, it sometimes fails with `AttributeError`, to be more precise, this is the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stats_tracker.py", line 140, in <module>
    print_interval(60)
  File "stats_tracker.py", line 108, in print_interval
    current_data = parse_table(get_data(URL))
  File "stats_tracker.py", line 30, in parse_table
    rows = table.find_all('tr')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'
```

The part of the code which produces the error is:

```
def get_data(URL):
    result = requests.get(URL)
    src = result.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(src, 'html.parser')
    table = soup.find("table", {"class": "stats_table"})

    if table is not None:
        return table
    else:
        time.sleep(1)
        get_data(URL)

def parse_table(table):
    data = []
    rows = table.find_all('tr') # <----- 30th line from the traceback
    for row in rows:
        cols = row.find_all('td')
        cols = [ele.text.strip() for ele in cols]
        data.append([ele for ele in cols if ele])

    for row in data:
        row[0] = int(row[0].replace(',', ''))
        row.reverse()

    return data
```

If I understand the error correctly, it means that `table`, which should be calling `find_all` method, is `None`, thus it cannot call the method which does not exist for `None`. I am not sure how it is possible to happen that the argument passed to `parse_table`, which is the value returned from `get_data(URL)`, is `None`.

How do I see that? After assigning the result of `soup.find(...)` to `table` I check whether it is not `None`, as I want to avoid the `AttributeError`. If it is not `None`, then I return `table`, which is later used as the argument of the `parse_table` - at this point `table.find_all('tr')` should work as expected. What if something went wrong and `table` is `None`? I call the `sleep` function and then I call the same function again, so the website can get fetched once more and maybe this time it will be correct.

I tested the code on two sources: the downloaded website as HTML and on the actual website. When it comes to the downloaded version, I could not get any errors to appear. When I run the script on the website, it works fine for about a day, fetching all information every 60 seconds, but then it crashes with the error I pasted above.

My question is: how can I improve the code to avoid the error I am getting over and over again (on multiple devices)? Is the `if ... is not None` not enough for that purpose, and if not - why? What can cause the code to fail after over one day of working, but not earlier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that if `table` is initially `none`, there will be nothing returned by the `get_data` function.

It will call itself again, but the return value for this second time is never used. What you should do is return the value from the second `get_data`.

```
if table is not None:
    return table
else:
    time.sleep(1)
    return get_data(URL) # return added here
```

Comment: I will add your solution to my code, if it does not crash in next two days, I will accept your answer!